# Производительность удаления элемента в LinkedList Java

Tags: java, linked-list

Всем привет! Все говорят,что удаление элемента в LinkedList происходит за константное время? Как это происходит?? С помощью метода remove(index) это явно не константное время,так как сначала надо найти этот индекс ,т.е.это уже O(n). Какой то блогер говорит ,что реализовать удаление за константное время можно только с использованием итератора.Но все же итератор ведь тоже проходит по всем элементам т.е.чем больше элементов ,тем больше времени требуется(опять O(n) ). Не могли бы объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, подразумеваются некие оговорки:

- либо удаление *первого* или *последнего* элемента в связанном списке
- либо *не учитывая время поиска* элемента по значению / индексу.

[Цитата:](https://habr.com/ru/post/337558/):

> Итак, что следует помнить о LinkedList, решая, использовать ли данную коллекцию:
>
> - не синхронизирована;
> - позволяет хранить любые объекты, в том числе `null` и повторяющиеся;
> - за константное время O(1) выполняются операции вставки и удаления первого и последнего элемента, операции вставки и удаления элемента из середины списка (***не учитывая время поиска позиции элемента, который осуществляется за линейное время***);
> - за линейное время O(n) выполняются операции поиска элемента по индексу и по значению.

Comment: Я думаю нельзя не учитывать время нахождение ,так как по другому невозможно удаление